# iText PDF Creation Error

Tags: java, pdf, netbeans, itext

I am using iText to create a PDF File from my Java file using NetBeans 8.2 . I have downloaded the iText JAR files from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/). My iText version is 7.0.2.

Here is the partial code (I am only including the import files and code related to iText from my Java File):
**Attendance.java**

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;

.
.
.
.

try {
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\Attendance.pdf"));
    DefaultListModel model1 = (DefaultListModel)present.getModel();            
    Document doc = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, output);
    doc.open();
    for (int i = 0; i < 68; i++) {
        doc.add(new Paragraph((String) model1.getElementAt(i)));
    }                      
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Attendance.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Problem:

I am getting the following 3 errors:

1. > no suitable constructor found for Document(no arguments)

[image: Document Error]

2. > cannot find symbol: getInstance(Document, OutputStream)

[image: getInstance]

3. > cannot find symbol: open()

[image: open]

I have followed a lot of tutorials like [this](https://howtodoinjava.com/apache-commons/create-pdf-files-in-java-itext-tutorial/), yet somehow they did not face the error I am facing even though I have used the same code. If someone has used iText to do such a thing, any advice would be appreciated. Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing up iText 5 tutorials and iText 7 code. You are using iText 7, but you are looking at an unofficial tutorial that describes how to use iText 5. iText 7 is a complete rewrite of iText 5, and the API is totally different.

Please take a look at the following tutorials on the *official* web site:

- [iText 7: jump-start tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial)
- [iText 7: Building blocks](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks)
- [iText 7: HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml)

A hello world example can be found [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/examples/chapter-1#1723-c01e01_helloworld.java) and looks like this:

```
//Initialize PDF writer
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
//Initialize PDF document
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
// Initialize document
Document document = new Document(pdf);
//Add paragraph to the document
document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
//Close document
document.close();
```

As you can see, it's completely different from the iText 5 code you are using.

**Important:** *ALWAYS* go to the [official web site](http://itextpdf.com) for information! There are many web sites that contain examples that give you the wrong advice, especially regarding digital signatures (outdated examples) and merging PDF's (wrong approach).

As for downloading iText, always start on the [download hub page](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/Java) because that contains the links to the most recent versions, including a compatibility matrix for the add-ons.

Comment: Hi Michaël. we answered simultaneously. I'll merge my answer into yours and then remove my answer.

Comment: You'll probably also want to point out that source forge is not the best site to download current iText versions from.

Comment: @mkl I added a link to the download page on the iText web site. That way, people also have a "how to install" video.

Comment: I am using iText 7 for .NET. I am getting "Document does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments".. Where did the example get the Document class if not